# How do I pick up a previous modification in VIM?

Tags: vim

If I did several modifications to the original file, i.e.

```
1 delete a line
2 insert some text
3 delete another line
4 delete the text added in step 2
5 insert some other text
6 ...
```

Now I want to recover the text deleted in step 2, is there a way of showing modifications and pick up something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:reg` to view all actions in `vim` then paste that deleted lines by pressing "2 ctrl + p

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers)

Answer (score 1):

If those are the only steps you've done, the deleted text should still be in a *numbered register*, which you can paste via e.g. `"2p`. If there have been too many edits in between, or the yank / delete was less than a full line, you won't find it there, though.

Then, you have to use Vim's *undo / redo* functionality to go back to that editing state, yank the text, then redo the changes. This can be done with the built-in `g-` and `:earlier` commands; plugins like *Gundo* or *undotree* aid in that by visualizing the undo tree.